# ¿Es posible ejecutar un app mediante un Intent, pero desde su ubicación o nombre de paquete?

Tags: android

Quiero saber si es posible ejecutar una app que se encuentra en su formato apk en la memoria interna o externa pero desde su ubicación o por su nombre de paquete, pero que esta no esta instalada en el dispositivo.Gracias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usando la clase [PackageManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html)  se puede abrir una aplicación por medio de un Intent, pero **la aplicación debe estar instalada dentro del dispositivo**, este es un ejemplo, en el cual necesitas el Package Name de la aplicación:

```
PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
Intent launchIntent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.mydominio.app");
startActivity(launchIntent);
```

Si requieres abrir una aplicación que no esta instalada dentro del dispositivo te recomiendo revisar esto:

> [**Android Instant Apps**](https://developer.android.com/topic/instant-apps/index.html) Apps nativas de Android, sin instalación Android
>   Instant Apps, un salto evolutivo en el uso compartido y el
>   descubrimiento de apps, permite ejecutar apps de Android de manera
>   instantánea sin necesidad de instalarlas. Gracias a Instant Apps,
>   puedes experimentar los aspectos que más te gustan de las apps
>   (interfaces de usuario rápidas y atractivas, alto rendimiento y
>   grandes capacidades) con solo un toque.

Esto es algo nuevo  y puede funcionar en dispositivos Android con Android 4.1+ (nivel de API 16) o versiones posteriores.